# Precompiled Handlebars template with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js, precompiled-templates

I have a handlebars template which I have manually precompiled and saved as - testTemplate.handlebars.

Now, in my requireJS + Backbone code I have the below function -

```
define(['text!../templates/testTemplate.handlebars'
       ],function(testTemplate){

           var myView = Backbone.View.extend(

              initialize: function(options){

                  this.template = Handlebars.template(testTemplate);

              },

              render: function(data){

                  $(this.el).html(this.template(data));
              }

           );
});
```

So the testTemplate.handlebars returns the Javascript code in a form of string which when passed to Handlebars.template returns the JS function. When I tried to print on the console the value I get in the this.template variable it shows -

```
function (n,r){return r=r||{},e.call(t,Handlebars,n,r.helpers,r.partials,r.data)}
```

But, when the line - `$(this.el).html(this.template(data));` of the render function executes, it gives an error message saying - Uncaught Typeerror : object has no method call. (Even though I can see a e.call function)

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Also, when I try to compile the template runtime the render function works.
While runtime compilation Handlebars.compile(testTemplate) the below function is returned -

```
function (e,t){return n||(n=r()),n.call(this,e,t)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have precompiled it, I'm not sure you need to make the .template call.  The function you are given should be executable AS the template itself.  So this:

```
$(this.el).html(this.template(data));
```

becomes this:

```
$(this.el).html(testTemplate(data));
```